# Telescope app keeps crashing - meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I'm new to Meteor and I'm trying to get Telescope running. I took the following steps;

- Install Meteor
- Install Meteorite
- Download or clone Telescope into /some/path
- cd /some/path
- Run mrt

But when I run localhost I keep getting the following error;

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log. /Users/Thomas/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
throw(ex);
^
ReferenceError: i18n is not defined
at app/Telescope/lib/locales/es.js:1:36
at app/Telescope/lib/locales/es.js:192:3
at /Users/Thomas/pcks_app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/Thomas/.meteor/tools/5bf1690853/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /Users/Thomas/pcks_app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Is there anyone who could point me in the right direction?

Many thanks, 
Thomas

Comment: Try running `mrt update` before you start your app

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that i18n is not defined.

As you can see here : https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/tree/master/packages

`i18n` is a namespace exposed by the `telescope-i18n` package. This is defined in `package.js` file by the `api.export()` function :

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.use(['ui'], 'client');
    api.add_files(['i18n.js'], ['client', 'server']);
    api.export('i18n');
});
```

First thing to check is that the package is in the package folder ; and that it is not corrupted. You should dowload it from the github repo and replace your to make sure.

Second thing that could go wrong is that the package is missing in the `.meteor/packages` file. Make sure it contain everything it needs. Here is the original from the repo :

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

backbone
accounts-base
accounts-ui
accounts-password
accounts-twitter
spiderable
email
crypto-md5
momentjs
standard-app-packages
rss
iron-router
mailchimp
telescope-i18n
fast-render
spin
autoform
collection2
accounts-facebook
iron-router-progress
telescope-tags
```

(https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/.meteor/packages)

Comment: Thanks Fabien! Your answer pointed me in the right direction, this is now fixed :) cheers, Thomas